# How to select every Monday date and every Friday date in the year

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

basically I want to be able to select monday and friday for every week in the year.

So for example this week coming i want 9/29/2014 and 10/3/2014, but i want this for every week in the year.

Comment: SELECT FROM a TABLE?   Show table DDL and what you've tried so far..

Comment: @Sparky no table, this is purely a system select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way (you might need to check which day of the week is setup to be the first, here I have Sunday as the first day of the week)

You can use a table with many rows (more than 365) to `CROSS JOIN` to in order to get a run of dates (a tally table).

My sys columns has over 800 rows in, you could use any other table or even `CROSS JOIN` a table onto itself to multiply up the number of rows

Here I used the `row_number` function to get a running count of rows and incremented the date by 1 day for each row:

```
select 
dateadd(d, row_number() over (order by name), cast('31 Dec 2013' as datetime)) as dt 
from sys.columns a
```

With the result set of dates now, it's trivial to check the day of week using `datepart()`

```
SELECT
    dt, 
    datename(dw, dt) 
FROM 
    (
        select 
            dateadd(d, row_number() over (order by name), cast('31 Dec 2013' as datetime)) as dt 
            from 
            sys.columns a
    ) as dates 
WHERE 
(datepart(dw, dates.dt) = 2 OR datepart(dw, dates.dt) = 6)
AND dt >= '01 Jan 2014' AND dt < '01 Jan 2015'
```

Edit:

Here's an example SqlFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21757

Edit 2:

If you want them on the same row, days of the week at least are constant, you know Friday is always 4 days after Monday so do the same but only look for Mondays, then just add 4 days to the Monday...

```
SELECT
    dt as MonDate, 
    datename(dw, dt) as MonDateName,
    dateadd(d, 4, dt) as FriDate,
    datename(dw, dateadd(d, 4, dt)) as FriDateName
FROM 
    (
        select 
            dateadd(d, row_number() over (order by name), cast('31 Dec 2013' as datetime)) as dt 
            from 
            sys.columns a
    ) as dates 
WHERE 
datepart(dw, dates.dt) = 2
AND dt >= '01 Jan 2014' AND dt < '01 Jan 2015'
AND dt >= '01 Jan 2014' AND dt < '01 Jan 2015'
```

Example SqlFiddle for this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/21764

(note that only a few rows come back because sys.columns is quite small on the SqlFiddle server, try another system table if this is a problem)

Comment: Interesting, can you show a way to select them in the same row?

Comment: What do you mean in the same row? You mean a column for each date?

Comment: Charleh like |monday|9/29|friday|10/3

Comment: Yeah you could do that but you'd have to `UNION` two resultsets... I'll post an example

Comment: You sure?  I mean 1 row would have both the monday date and the friday date

Comment: I was just thinking dateadd myself

Answer (score 3):

You can use a suitable table with numbers, like the master..spt_values table as basis for the range generation:

```
;WITH dates AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number,CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE)) d
    FROM master..spt_values WHERE TYPE = 'p'
    AND number < 366
    )

SELECT 
    Week = DATEPART(WEEK, d), 
    DayOfWeek = DATENAME(dw, d), 
    Date = d
FROM dates
WHERE DATENAME(dw, d) IN ('Monday', 'Friday')
-- or use datepart instead as datename might be specific to language
-- WHERE DATEPART(dw, d) IN (2,6)
```

Sample output:

```
Week        DayOfWeek                      Date
----------- ------------------------------ ----------
1           Friday                         2014-01-03
2           Monday                         2014-01-06
2           Friday                         2014-01-10
3           Monday                         2014-01-13
3           Friday                         2014-01-17
4           Monday                         2014-01-20
4           Friday                         2014-01-24
5           Monday                         2014-01-27
5           Friday                         2014-01-31
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT extract(isodow from "date_source")` as datee 1-monday 7-sunday

and then in WHERE write `datee IN ('1','2'....)`