# Inserting multiple rows into table with 1 static column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table column structure like this

- `[ Name , DateName , Sum ]`

  I selected all names I need so I have multiple rows with data like this
- `[ SomeName , NULL , NULL ]`

I would like to add for each  Name 7 DateNames , is it possible with something like outer apply ? Just to point out  the table I'm inserting into is `#temptable`

here is a print of 2 tables i would like to combine http://prntscr.com/ikv213 so for each Name i would like to add all 7 days

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: I think he wants a fairly tricky full outer join on itself, which I have never done especially on a date range, but tbh I cba to look into it unless he confirms

Comment: @GordonLinoff i added prntscr of datas in my question , tnx for editing my question tho

Comment: is `DateName` a `VarChar`,  `Date` or a `DateTime` field?

Comment: I think you misunderstand how SQL databases work, however I think you *can* do this but it's fiddly

Comment: @MrHeelis nvarchar(50) cuz DATENAME() returns it like that so i took that type for the column

Comment: ok you can't do this if it's not a `date` this guy does something similar but he uses a date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088814/how-to-select-every-monday-date-and-every-friday-date-in-the-year

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    INSERT INTO #FinalTable ([Name],[DateName]) 
    SELECT [Name],DN.[DateName] 
    FROM OrganizationUnit 
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT [DateName] FROM #DateName) DN
```

OUTER APPLY was the answer .My friend helped me and it returned the desired value , thanks all for trying but i think this is the best solution.

Comment: I don't know why i got -1 but it is probably because i failed to explain my problem , sorry if that's the case ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `CROSS JOIN` for each Name with 7 days

Just like this.

```
SELECT t1.NAME,WeekD.DayName
FROM [YourTable] AS t1 CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Monday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Tuesday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Wednesday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Thurthday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Firday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Saturday' AS DayName
    UNION
    SELECT 'Sunday' AS DayName
)AS WeekD
```